# Mobx: Change values of a store from another store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

I am using mobx-react-lite with hooks.

I have two store.
`AuthStore`
`SomeOtherStore`

This is my dummy `AuthStore`

```
import { observable, decorate, action } from 'mobx';
import { createContext } from 'react';
import { ROLE_LOGISTICS_MANAGER } from '../settings/constants';
import AuthService from '../services/AuthService';

class AuthStore {
  constructor() {
    this.authService = new AuthService();
  }

  currentMode = ROLE_LOGISTICS_MANAGER;

  authenticating = true;

  isLoggedIn = false;

  userId = null;

  loginLoading = false;

  login = async params => {
    this.loginLoading = true;
    try {
      const data = await this.authService.loginAsync(params);
      this.loginLoading = false;
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      this.loginError = e;
    } finally {
      this.loginLoading = false;
    }
  };
}
decorate(AuthStore, {
  currentMode: observable,
  loginLoading: observable,
  isLoggedIn: observable,
  authenticating: observable,
  userId: observable,
  fetchUser: action,
  login: action
});
export const AuthStoreContext = createContext(new AuthStore());
```

Now Lets say I want to change isLoggedIn from another store, 
How can I do that? I tried to find ways in docs, couldn't find a solid solution.
I am using hooks with mobx-react-lite
So normally I use mobx like

```
const authStore = useContext(AuthStoreContext);
```

Comment: What is `SomeOtherStore`?

Comment: @lx1412 lets say i have products, and on some api call i want to change autheticating to true (the authstore)

Answer (score 1):

It's a common pattern to have stores as properties on a `RootStore`, each having references back to the root. So you could have a structure like:

```
class RootStore {
  constructor (auth, ui) {
    this.auth = new AuthStore(this)
    this.ui = new UiStore(this)
  }
}

class AuthStore {
  constructor (rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore
  }

  logout() {
    this.isLoggedIn = false
  }
}

decorate(AuthStore, {
  logout: action
})
```

Then, when you need to call a function on another store, you can use the reference to the root as a pathway. The pattern's described in more detail [here](https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html). A possible example of use with `useContext` might be:

```
const { someStore } = useContext(rootStoreContext)
someStore.rootStore.auth.logout()
```